implement no overlapping constraint between 2 tasks in MIP
I have 2 sets of tasks each with start and end times, I want to enforce a constraint that ensures that 2 tasks do not overlap with each other. I know that in constraint programming we have specialised constraints such as AddNoOverlap, but how can I achieve the above through mixed integer programming (open source solvers). Below is the starter code :
# start and end times of a pair of tasks
# task 1
s1 = 9
d1 = 10

# task 2
s2 = 3
d2 = 5

def no_overlap(model, s1, d1, s2, d2):
    # ensure that task 1 and task 2 do not overlap
    pass


Could you please provide more clarity regarding how start and end times are defined

Incorporating the suggestion from Erwin in the below revised implementation.
You can achieve the no-overlap between 2 tasks by creating a binary variable, say bin_task. If bin_task == 1 this implies task 1 precedes task 2, else if bin_task == 0 then this implies that task 2 precedes task 1.
Then write 2 indicator constraints - a) if bin_task == 1 then enforce s1 + d1 <= s2 which is task 2 starts after completion of task 1 and b) if bin_task == 0 then enforce s2 + d2 <= s1 which is task 1 starts after completion of task 2.
below is my implementation through or tool's linear solver library mathopt.
from ortools.math_opt.python import mathopt

model = mathopt.Model(name="")

s1 = 9
d1 = 10
s2 = 3
d2 = 5

def no_overlap(model, s1, d1, s2, d2):
    big_M = 100 # set accordingly
    # binary variable == 1 implies task 1 preecedes task 2
    bin_task = model.add_binary_variable(name = "bin_task")
    
    # if `bin_task == 1` then enforce `s1 + d1 <= s2`
    model.add_linear_constraint(s1 + d1 - s2 <= big_M * (1 - bin_task))

    # if `bin_task == 0` then enforce `s2 + d2 <= s1` 
    model.add_linear_constraint(s2 + d2 - s1 <= big_M * bin_task)

    params = mathopt.SolveParameters(enable_output=True)
    result = mathopt.solve(model, mathopt.SolverType.GSCIP, params=params)

    print("Task 1 preeded Task 2:", result.variable_values()[bin_task])
    
no_overlap(model, s1, d1, s2, d2)
# task 2 precedes task 1 since bin_task == 0


This can be done a bit more compactly: only one binary variable is needed. And the constraint bin_task_1 + bin_task_2 == 1 is not needed either.

Many thanks Erwin for the valuable feedback. I have incorporated your advice in the above (revised) formulation.
